# Unquoute not working for maps even with Macro.escape

Tags: elixir

I have the following code:

```
defmodule Foo do
  defmacro __using__(options) do
    attrs = Keyword.get(options, :attrs, Macro.escape(%{}))
    quote do
      def show, do: IO.inspect(unquote(attrs))
    end
  end
end

defmodule MacroBug do
  use Foo,
    attrs: Macro.escape(%{:correct => true})
end
```

This code prints:

```
iex(5)> MacroBug.show
{:%{}, [], [correct: true]}
{:%{}, [], [correct: true]}
```

It should be `%{correct: false}`, no? if no, what's the correctly way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#escape/2-comparison-to-kernel-specialforms-quote-2), one should explicitly `Macro.escape/2` *values*.

In your example, the issue is you actually quoting the map twice. Check these three macros:

```elixir
defmodule Escape do
  defmacro q(opts) do
    IO.inspect(opts, label: "quote")
    quote do: IO.inspect(unquote(opts), label: "unquote")
  end

  defmacro e(opts) do
    value = IO.inspect(Macro.escape(%{foo: %{}}), label: "escape")
    quote do: IO.inspect(unquote(value), label: "unescape")
  end

  defmacro e!(opts) do
    value = IO.inspect(%{foo: %{}}, label: "escape!")
    quote do: IO.inspect(unquote(value), label: "unescape!")
  end
end
```

The first two are fairly equivalent and happily produce the expected result.

```elxiir
iex|1 ▸ Escape.q %{foo: %{}}
escape: {:%{}, [], [foo: {:%{}, [], []}]}
unescape: %{foo: %{}}
%{foo: %{}}
iex|2 ▸ Escape.q %{foo: %{}}
quote: {:%{}, [], [foo: {:%{}, [], []}]}
unquote: %{foo: %{}}
%{foo: %{}}
```

The third one, though, raises, because one cannot pass `%{foo: %{}}` through the AST transformation boundary. That said, for the latter case, like the value created within the macro context, one should escape it.

For values passed from outside of the macro, [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) does it all for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I edited the question with a minimal reproducible example. Following your question the result should be `%{correct: false},` no?

Comment: `attrs: Macro.escape(%{:correct => true})` → `attrs: %{:correct => true}`